# Bootstrap: change active menu item background

Tags: css, nav

How can I change in this section of code the background color of the navigation when an anchor point is selected? I just want to have a border-bottom under the navigation link.

this is the code:

```
 <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>

                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#ark">Nav 2</a>
                </li>

                <li class="">
                    <a href="/table.html">Nav 3</a>
                </li>

                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#ausstattung">Nav 4</a>
                </li>

                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#lage">Nav 5</a>
                </li>

                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#contact">Nav 6</a>
                </li>

                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#kontakt">Nav 7</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top"></a>

        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar how to change that bg color and put a border-bottom??

Comment: I solved it for you. Kindly check.

Comment: can you create `jsfiddle` for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I understood. Change the below line:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #1a242f;
}
```

To this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1a242f;
    background: none;
}
```

This can be found in `bootstrap.min.css`. If you don't want to edit this, just add the above code at the end.

Comment: This was the answer :)